# no responses from ping on localhost

Tags: networking

I am trying to ping the loopback on a remote machine connected through ssh, however I do not receive any answer.

```
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 100ms
```

In the following, I ran a few diagnostic program to see what is wrong but everything seems normal to my untrained eyes.

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 <name_of_device>
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

```
$ ifconfig lo
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 52  bytes 4188 (4.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 52  bytes 4188 (4.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0
```

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 67.207.67.2
nameserver 67.207.67.3
```

```
$ sudo iptables -L 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux <name_of_device> 4.19.0-10-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ cat /etc/nftables.conf 
# /usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;

        # Always allow SSH access
        tcp dport 22 accept

        ct state established,related log prefix "DROPPING PACKET: " drop

        ip saddr 192.0.2.192/27 accept
        ip saddr 192.0.2.96/27 accept
        ip saddr 192.0.2.0/24 drop

        ip saddr 198.51.100.69/32 accept
        ip saddr 198.51.100.42/32 log prefix "DROPPING PACKET: " drop
        ip saddr 198.51.100.32/28 accept
        ip saddr 199.51.100.0/24 tcp dport { 80, 443 } accept
        ip saddr 199.51.100.0/24 drop

        ip saddr 203.0.113.0/24 tcp dport { 22, 443, 5432 } log prefix "INVALID TRAFFIC NETWORK: " drop
        ip saddr 203.0.113.0/24 tcp dport 80 accept
    }
}
```

Furthermore, this machine fails to ping anything on the Internet.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 55ms
```

And from the outside it is also not possible to ping it.

```
$ ping 138.68.93.123
PING 138.68.93.123 (138.68.93.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 138.68.93.123: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=7.75 ms
^C
--- 138.68.93.123 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 1 received, 80% packet loss, time 4050ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.746/7.746/7.746/0.000 ms
```

At this point I have ran out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the default gateway? And, some linux versions implement a firewall with nftables instead of iptables, please check if any rules are present ...

Comment: I added two new CLI interfaces. Changing the config files didn't seem to do much. Maybe it has to be modified in some other way than through an editor? What do you mean by checking the default gateway?

Comment: This config file is read by a service, which loads it into the Kernel... After changing that config file, you have to reload that service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you have the reason - the rule ct state [....] drops all incoming packets, even if they are related to an ping to localhost Interface. You should reconsider that rule... you should at least allow traffic  on the loopback Interface...

Comment: This is outstanding! Never knew there was another protocol for firewalls other than `iptables`. Thank you very much :)